# R function across dataframe based on flexible subsetting/conditional

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have the following example dataframe in R:

```
SampleID = c("A25", "A25", "A25", "A25", "A25", "A25", "A25", "A25", "A25", "A25", "A26", "A26", "A26", "A26", "A26", "A26", "A26", "A26", "A26", "A26")
MaterialID = c("DR1", "DR4", "DR9", "DR10", "DR12", "DR14", "DR15", "DR18", "DR23", "DR25", "DR3", "DR5", "DR9", "DR11", "DR12", "DR13", "DR15", "DR18", "DR23", "DR26")
Concentration = c(0.15, 0.02, 0.43, 0.56, 0.13, 1.2, 0.08, 0.03, 1.78, 0.65, 0.86, 0.04, 0.67, 1.2, 0.11, 0.04, 0.24, 0.08, 1.01, 0.95)
MyData = data.frame(SampleID, MaterialID, Concentration)
```

Which looks likes this:

```
   SampleID MaterialID Concentration
1       A25        DR1          0.15
2       A25        DR4          0.02
3       A25        DR9          0.43
4       A25       DR10          0.56
5       A25       DR12          0.13
6       A25       DR14          1.20
7       A25       DR15          0.08
8       A25       DR18          0.03
9       A25       DR23          1.78
10      A25       DR25          0.65
11      A26        DR3          0.86
12      A26        DR5          0.04
13      A26        DR9          0.67
14      A26       DR11          1.20
15      A26       DR12          0.11
16      A26       DR13          0.04
17      A26       DR15          0.24
18      A26       DR18          0.08
19      A26       DR23          1.01
20      A26       DR26          0.95
```

I also have a list of MaterialIDs that I am specifically interested in, stored in the variable `MaterialID_sub`.

```
MaterialID_sub = c("DR1", "DR4", "DR10", "DR12", "DR14", "DR18", "DR23", "DR28")
```

I would like to do the following:

If a `SampleID` has at least 6 out of the 8 `MaterialIDs` specified in `MaterialID_sub`, sum the concentrations of the IDs in `MaterialID_sub` for that sample and then multiply by 2. For example, Sample A25 contains 7 out of the 8 IDs in `MaterialID_sub`, and the concentrations of these 7 IDs would then be summed to equal 3.87, and then multiplied by 2 to equal 7.74. Sample A26 however does not have at least 6 of the IDs listed in `MaterialID_sub`, so would not be summed.

The output would look something like this, where only those samples that meet the criteria above are included in the output (e.g., A25):

```
SampleID   Sum*2   
A25        7.74     
Etc.
```

Note that the example I have provided is just a small subset of a much larger dataset that includes hundreds of `SampleIDs`, and the actual number of `MaterialIDs` for a given sample is much larger. So scaling up is important. If there was a way to incorporate this code into a dplyr pipeline that would be great. The solution to this seems to be just outside my grasp of R, as my attempts thus far have failed.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could group by 'SampleID', `filter` those SampleID based on the condition i.e. at least 6 MaterialID should match that from MaterialID_Sub and only those matched row should be kept, then get the `sum` of 'Concentration' and multiply by 2

```
library(dplyr)
MyData %>% 
   group_by(SampleID) %>%
   filter(sum(MaterialID %in% MaterialID_sub)>=6,
           MaterialID %in% MaterialID_sub) %>% 
   summarise(Sum = sum(Concentration) * 2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# SampleID   Sum
#  <chr>    <dbl>
#1 A25       7.74
```

Comment: akrun, thanks much. This solution is easy to follow and does the job.